# Questions about byte order during mips traditional 5-stage cpu design

Tags: mips, verilog, cpu, pipeline, fpga

I'm working on developing a traditional MIPS 5-stage pipeline cpu using verilog on a FPGA platform. My reference material shows an example with big-endian byte order, while I decide to develop a little-endian cpu. My question is whether there will be difference when decoding instructions  or loading/storing data and what is it specifically?

I used two X-compilers which are little endian and big endian respectively to compile a piece of sample assembly code as follows:
[image]
At the center is the big endian translation with little endian on the right and original assembly code on the left.

Obviously , those two translation are in reverse order of each byte per instruction , is this the effect of byte order ?
So will the instruction decode module decode instruction in reverse order with different endianess ?

Comment: Never show pictures of code.  Or output.

Comment: If you're building your own CPU you can do anything you like.  You can store in one order and reverse it, or you can design everything to use the same order.  I just built a super small really RISC processor and used big-endian.  It just seemed more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

There will be differences, which occur when the load/store access size of e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit does not match the native bus size, e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit.

The endianess then determines how data is converted to/from the internal data and the external bus, and thus the external memory space.

This [classical example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Classical_example) shows the difference, then the internal data size is 32-bit and the external bus and memory is 8-bit.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether there will be difference when decoding instructions or loading/storing data and what is it specifically?

You should assemble the bytes into words within Instruction Memory and Data Memory using the appropriate endianness, such that pipeline stages including IF/fetch, ID/decode, EX/alu, MEM and WB are unaffected by the choice in endianness.

More specifically, I would have Instruction Memory assemble bytes in the appropriate endian ordering when instructions are read as 32-bit words by the Instruction Fetch operation, and, have the Data Memory assemble/disassemble bytes in the appropriate endian ordering when reading/writing 32-bit or 16-bit data from/into the cache.

You have more flexibility with the Instruction Memory since it never has to work with bytes or halves.  In theory it could byte swap each instruction word while loading into the cache from main memory.  This is not appropriate in the Data Memory since we don't know at cache line/block load time how the various bytes in the line will be used (whether as bytes, halves, or words).